# Tensorflow batch matrix multiplication

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to multiply a batched matrix X with dimension [batch_size, m, n] with a matrix Y of size[n,l], how should I do this?

It looks like I cannot just use matmul. Is there a neat way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tf.einsum` with equation `ijk,kl->ijl`, i.e. multiply the last dimension of X and first dimension of Y, and sum it over:

```py
x = np.arange(12).astype(np.int32).reshape(2,3,2)
y = np.arange(6).astype(np.int32).reshape(2,3)
​
X = tf.constant(x)
Y = tf.constant(y)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(tf.einsum('ijk,kl->ijl', X, Y)))
#[[[ 3  4  5]
#  [ 9 14 19]
#  [15 24 33]]

# [[21 34 47]
#  [27 44 61]
#  [33 54 75]]]
```

The corresponding solution from `numpy`:

```py
x @ y
#array([[[ 3,  4,  5],
#        [ 9, 14, 19],
#        [15, 24, 33]],

#       [[21, 34, 47],
#        [27, 44, 61],
#        [33, 54, 75]]], dtype=int32)

np.dot(x, y)
#array([[[ 3,  4,  5],
#        [ 9, 14, 19],
#        [15, 24, 33]],

#       [[21, 34, 47],
#        [27, 44, 61],
#        [33, 54, 75]]], dtype=int32)
```